# Надо организовать RTP прием\отдачу аудио через ffmpeg

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, rtp

Помогите пожалуйста. Не могу даже понять, с чего бы начать реализовывать данную проблему:
известен IP, порт и SDP. Надо организовать (сейчас хотя бы) прием по RTP аудио с обработкой в ffmpeg из разных источников: на сервере открывается несколько сокетов и в них идет поток. Каждый поток должен писаться в свой буффер, потоконезависимый. 
Можете, пожалуйста, написать минимальный шаблон класса, в котором осуществляется: открытие сокета, прием из него потока в буффер в формате пригодном для последующей обработки ffmpeg. 
Вообще дальше в программе эти данные из буфферов будут хвататься классом фильтра ffmpeg, который будет микшировать данные и отсылать их обратно отправителям. Предполагается, что для каждого соединения будет создаваться объект из класса RTP соединения. Еще использую boost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открывайте формат так:

```
avformat_open_input(&ifmtctx, "rtp://IP:PORT?option=val", ifmt, nullptr);
```

Доступные опции для RTP можно поглядеть тут: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtp. FFmpeg использует стекирование протоколов: RTP работает поверх UDP, поэтому будут полезны и эти опции: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#udp

Опции можно передать и через словарь (последний аргумент), тогда вызов будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
av_dict_set(&opts, "option", "value", 0);
...
avformat_open_input(&ifmtctx, "rtp://IP:PORT", ifmt, &opts);
// Здесь opts будет содержать в себе только те опции, обработать которые FFmpeg не смог
av_dict_free(&opts);
```

По разбору SDP я вам уже отвечал.

Для аплода RTP используется точно такая же схема.

Как сервер (когде к НЕМУ подключаются, а не ОН подключается) FFmpeg тоже умеет работать, но крайне плохо. Рассматривать эту возможность не стоит.

Comment: А то,что будет приходить по RTP содержится в ifmtctx?

Comment: Да, работаешь с ним в обычном режиме. С небольшим отличием: из твоего SDP нужно ему подсказать, что там за стримы есть. Но, как я понял, ты это знаешь как делать. Если нет - пиши другой вопрос.